# How create style of TextView as Spinner's style

Tags: java, android, textview, spinner

It is possible programmatically create TextView with style as current main style of Spinner in system (with border, drop icon, shadow)?

add: without create xml-files. Only programmatically.

Comment: if you not have real answer please don't spam

Comment: see, 2 people liked my comment so, in a way it answers you, but no one will give you code, or wait till; if someone does, till then try, come up with errors, your ideas :)